# Counting occurrences of numbers in a C array (vector)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, vector

I am trying to implement a solution to the following problem with vectors (arrays) in C.
I want to input a number and the number of times it occurs.

Here is an Example:

```
Imput n:  5

Imput num 1: 8
Imput num 2: 9
Imput num 3: 8
Imput num 4: 5
Imput num 5: 5
```

The program will now show this:

```
Number 8: 2 occurences
Number 9: 1 occurences
Number 5: 2 occurences
```

but mine show:

```
Number 8: 2 occurences
Number 9: 1 occurences
Number 8: 2 occurences
Number 5: 2 occurences
Number 5: 2 occurences
```

how can i do??? TY

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main ()
{
    int vett1[SIZE], vett2[SIZE];
    int n, i, j;
    int flag;

    printf ("Imput n: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf ("Imput %d di %d: ", i+1, n);
        scanf  ("%d", &vett1[i]);
    }

    printf ("\n\nYour vector: : ");

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ", vett1[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        flag=0;

        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (vett1[j] == vett1[i])
            {
                flag++;
            }
        }

        vett2[i] = flag;
    }

    printf ("\n\n");

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf ("Number %d: %d occurencese\n", vett1[i], vett2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Implement a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: If you are asking about your code, it would be helpful to see it.

Comment: He didn't even read the FAQ. Why do you bother with helping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to keep track of (1) numbers, and (2) the number of occurences. Think like this: If you were doing it by hand, with pencil and paper, and not with a computer, how would you do it?

You would probably need a piece of paper with a small table on it, with numbers in the left column and the number of occurences in the right column. You'd then go through the numbers (in your case 8, 9, 8, 5, 5) and for each number, you would check if it's in your table. If it already is in the table, increment the count by one. If it isn't in the table, put it on a new line, with the count 1.

Now all you need to do is to implement this table not as a table on paper, but as some sort of data structure.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Paper and pencil are my friends but i can't just find the right way to not count the same number more than once... how to check if the number is in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Your last code write that:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf ("Number %d: %d occurencese\n", vett1[i], vett2[i]);
}
```

Which you print n times of each input number to show the corresponding occurencese, so I think you just need to change the print out function is ok.

Comment: what you mean with "change the print out function"?

Comment: you got the correct result, but print it out with a wrong format.
So, you just need to update(change) your print out function to the cases once only.

Answer (score 0):

You want to see each number only once. There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Whenever you examine a number, first see if it's the first occurrence of this number in the array. If not, just ignore it. Very inefficient, because when looking at the n'th element, you need to go back and examine all those before it.
2. Like the above, but combine the first occurrence verification with the counting. You have two nested loops, with `i` and `j`. If the `j` loop sees `vett1[j] == vett1[i]` where `j<i`, it means this isn't the first occurrence of this number. Ignore it. This is as efficient as your current solution.
3. Sort - Use `qsort` to sort the array. Then go over it just once. Now all occurences of each number come one after another, so you can easily count them with just one pass of the array. This is the most efficient way, but just a bit complicated.

Comment: Than Yoy for the answer! I'm new on programming so how can i sort the vetor? i just know the bubble-sorting algorithm...

Comment: You may want solution #2 to avoid sorting. You can implement bubble-sort, or use C's standard `qsort` function, which implements quick-sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct you just need to modify your last printing for loop just check the condition there that if the element is similar to previous then skip printing again.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(vett1[i+1] == vett1[i])
        continue;
    else
        printf("Number %d %d occurence",vett1[i],vett2[i]);
}
```